# Javascript tic-tac-toe timer

Tags: javascript

I am making a tic-tac-toe game and I was proposed with idea to make a counter which would say how much time is left to make a move. Lets say 10 seconds. How to make timer which would run in background and reset each time a move is done or stop the game making a person who didn't make a move in time a looser ?
Heres my HTML :

```
<html>
<header>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css"/>
</header>
<body>
<div class="centered" id="content">
  <div class="row" id="r1">
    <div class="field empty" id="f1"></div>
    <div class="field empty" id="f4"></div>
    <div class="field empty" id="f7"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="r2">
    <div class="field empty" id="f2"></div>
    <div class="field empty" id="f5"></div>
    <div class="field empty" id="f8"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="r3">
    <div class="field empty" id="f3"></div>
    <div class="field empty" id="f6"></div>
    <div class="field empty" id="f9"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="application/javascript" src="scripts/jquery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="scripts/scripts.js"></script>         
</body>
</html>
```

And here's javascript/jquery :

```
var changeTurn = false;
var turn = true;
var classCross = "cross";
var classCircle = "circle";
var classEmpty = "empty";    

$('.field').click(function(event) {
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  var div = $(this);
  changeTurn = false;
  if (turn) {
    if (fieldIsFree(div)) {
      div.removeClass(classEmpty);
      div.addClass(classCircle);
      changeTurn = true;
    }
  }
  else {
    if (fieldIsFree(div)) {
      div.removeClass(classEmpty);
      div.addClass(classCross);
      changeTurn = true;
    }
  }
  if (changeTurn)
    turn = !turn;
  return false;
});

function fieldIsFree(tmpdiv) {
  if (tmpdiv.hasClass(classCross))
    return false;
  if (tmpdiv.hasClass(classCircle))
    return false;
  return true;
}
```

Comment: jsfiddle.. if possible would be great..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented a very boring game that shows how you might approach this.  The main thing you need to take care of is keeping track of the return value of setTimeout.  This value should be used to cancel the current timeout (using `clearTimeout`), which you would want to do every time a player moves or if the game is paused or stopped.

```js
"use strict";

var timer;
var button;
var timeLeft;
var label;

function countdown() {
  if (timeLeft) {
    label.innerHTML = timeLeft;
    timeLeft--;
    timer = setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
  } else {
    label.innerHTML = "Fail";
    timer = undefined;
  }
}

function takeMove() {
  // timer will only be undefined if the game is not started
  if (typeof(timer) === "undefined") {
    button.innerHTML = "Move";
    timeLeft = 10;
    countdown();
  } else {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timeLeft = 10;
    countdown();
  }
}

function init() {
  button = document.getElementById("move");
  label = document.getElementById("label");
  button.addEventListener("click", takeMove);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
```

```html
<div id="game-board">
  <button id="move">Start</button>
</div>
<div id="output">
  Time left: <span id="label"><span>
</div>
```

Comment: An explanation of the approach would be great.

Comment: Thanks ! This "Run code snippet" made your code really helpfull. I didn't know you can do that.

Comment: @Plohej there's a control for adding snippets in the editor.  Looks like a page with open/close angle brackets on it

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

define timeout Reference globally

```
var timeoutReference;
```

At the start/change of the turn

```
// the previous player made his move on time, clear his timeout
clearTimeout(timeoutReference);
// set a new timeout for the new player
timeoutReference = setTimeout(function(player) {
    return function() { setLose(player); }
}(currentPlayer), 10000);
```

Where `currentPlayer` is either cross or circle and `setLose` is the function invoked that handles ending the game prematurely and showing that the player inputted lost and the other player won.

In `setTimeout` we have used a closure to keep the player reference that would lose after the timeout in the scope of the function.